# How do I know what COLUMN my cursor is at in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Sometimes I want to know what column my cursor is at, so I can see how many characters I have left til the print margin.

This is a common functionality in most IDEs and text editors, but I couldn't find it in Xcode.

Is it possible to enable this or see it somewhere?

Comment: The natural place for this to appear in Xcode would be the jump bar. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and reference radar://9245044 to request this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turns out as for now (Xcode 4.3.2), it can't be done.

My solution was eventually moving to AppCode :)

Answer (score 30):

Open Xcode's Preferences, go to the Text Editing tab, Editing subtab, and check the "Page guide at column: 80" box. That will display a vertical line at 80 columns in the editor.

Comment: I don't get it, it just puts a gray line at column 4, it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: You can set to 80 if you prefer to see a print margin.

Comment: yeah well.. I asked how can I see how far I am from the print margin, not how to actually see a print margin.

Comment: This answer works for me - all I really want to know is where to end my comments at to avoid going over 80 characters long, and a vertical guide line actually works better for that than a textual position listing. I edited this answer for clarity.

Comment: I use it at position 36 for variable indentation.  I want a column position indicator back so I can see *both* where I want variable names to start and comments to end.

Comment: In Xcode10 its in "Display" and not "Editing" tab, but it still does not solve the problem

Answer (score 22):

EDIT Oct 6, 2021:

Holy moly. Xcode 13 now shows both the line and column number in the IDE! It took ten years but Apple listened.

---

Original Post:

If you find this post, please log in to the [Apple Bug Reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com) site and report this as a bug against the Xcode developer tool.  Mention that Xcode needs to provide an option to display the cursor column position and that the page guide is insufficient.  Apple should mark it as a duplicate request of bug #8315595.

The more requests they get the greater the likelihood they'll repair it and this *is* a very useful feature for many developers.

Comment: It is astonishing how backwards Xcode is compared to most modern IDEs... good thinking re filing a bug, that is definitely how this should be treated.

Comment: Hilariously enough, they implemented it incorrectly. It counts characters, not columns, so it can't handle tabs

Comment: Where are column numbers shown in Xcode 14?

Comment: @FeifanZ bottom right of the screen if the Debug Area is collapsed, or on the right side of the separator bar above the Debug Area if it is shown.